# Passing parameters using url scheme

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, url-scheme

I am working on a app which could be launched over a URL. I have already defined my url scheme using xcode on info page. I filled for identifier my Bundle identifier and for URL Schemes myapp.

Now if I try to open in safari myapp://foo, it launches my app and stops at my breakpoint in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
```

method.

Problem is annotation, url, application, sourceapplication parameters are nil. So I can not pass parameters...

[image]

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targeting/testing on?

Comment: Are you saying that this method's `url` variable is nil, or that the parameterString of `url` (since it's an NSURL) is nil?  How are you determining that it's nil?

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing a valid encoded link? I've often used this delegate method but I've never experienced that behavior!

Comment: @BillyLazzaro nsurl is nil

Comment: @Alexander Like I told in my question, I am trying to open the address myapp://foo, and it launches my app, but I do not get the string foo. I have also tried myapp://?foo=1234, no luck...

Comment: @Mert Okay, could have been an example... Are you trying in simulator or device?

Comment: @Alexander I have tried on simulator and on device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unnecessary time loss, I have found out, the problem was the debugger. It shows the url is nil and if I try to print description it says

```
Printing description of url:
<nil>
```

But If I try to NSLog it shows the url.
And if put the following code in the method

```
if (! url) {
    return NO;
}
```

The debugger shows also the url.

Comment: In this case, make sure your project is in "debug" mode and not "release" mode. In release mode, which is default, a lot of things can get optimized out

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your project is in debug mode!? See here http://nerdwa.com/index.php/2011/09/debugrelease-schemes-in-xcode-4/

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. I have also many preprocessor directives like #ifdef DEBUG in my code

Comment: Well sometimes the debugger does this especially on the device. As long as your nslog sees the value you should be ok. If you break and the type "po url" what do you get back?

Comment: Also may I ask how you will be passing data in? Might I suggest using a base64 encoded json object. This allows for structured data and it's super simple to do

Comment: Yes like in my answer I see the value as expected, after then I can parse and so on.. I could not mark my answer as correct, because I have to wait one day...

Comment: Actually like I already told in my question I just type the addressbar of safari myapp://fooo. So I do not call it from my another app. All encoding has to be done by safari